# Selenium Remote Driver Error forwarding the new session cannot find

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I am using Selenium Grid. I have updated the VM (node) to Windows 10 recently, and it doesn't work anymore. Here is the details

I register this VM Win10 as node to the Grid by:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Selenium\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.50.34:4444/grid/register/ -trustAllSSLCertificates
```

(this worked fine with VM Win8 before) I can see on the grid that this VM Win10 is registered with 3 browser IE11, FF and Chrome

In my code, I create web driver by this:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("applicationName", "qa-user");
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.50.34:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I always get this error when I execute the test

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=ANY, browserName=firefox, applicationName=qa-user, version=}]

It worked like this before with all browsers on the node. I don't know if I miss some settings on the node VM Win10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your test specifying the path to IEDriver directly in your class ?

Personally for my VM Win10 i use this :

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -port 4444 -host x.x.x.x
```

Java class :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\IEUser\\Desktop\\selenium-grid\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=ANY, browserName=firefox, applicationName=qa-user, version=}]

This error show that your try to create a new browser session with a capability that the Grid doesn't know about.